# Multiple IN() checks on joined table with mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with user data and a m:n relationship table for the assignment to different groups. To filter all the Users which belong to group 1 and 2 I wrote the following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN user_groups AS g ON g.uid = u.uid
WHERE 1 IN (g.gid) AND 2 IN (g.gid)
```

Unfortunately this statement does not work. The result is empty, but there are users wich are in both groups. When I make a second join to user_groups it works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN user_groups AS g ON g.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN user_groups AS g2 ON g2.uid = u.uid
WHERE 1 IN (g.gid) AND 2 IN (g2.gid)
```

Can anybody explain to me, what is wrong with the first statement?
It wold be great if anybody could show me, how to solve this problem with one join, because I have to check a various amount of groups.

Thank you in advance,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

In your first query try replacing AND with OR. The column gid cant be both 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I tried the OR connector and It works like it should. I get all users which are in group 1 OR in group 2. But is there also a chance to get all users which are in group 1 AND in group 2?

Comment: Yes, this will get all records that have one, the other, or both.

Comment: And do you know a way to change the query, to get only the users which have both groups?

Comment: Try this:  SELECT * FROM user as u where exists(select null from user_groups ug1 where ug1.gid = 1 and ug1.uid = u.uid) and exists(select null from user_groups ug2 where ug2.gid = 2 and ug2.uid = u.uid)

Comment: Yes, this works for me. But I think I will use the version with two joins, because the performance ist better! Thank you, maple_shaft!!!